# Need help keeping a timer running when the game is not with Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in c# unity, and I am having trouble keeping a timer going while the application is closed. I can use TimeSpan fine, and find the ticks when the game closes, then ticks now, and convert it into seconds.

I have this premium currency in the game that I want to go up every x seconds(for this example I was using 10 to test). I have a countdown going in the game called showTimeLeft, and it decreases by 1 per second. I also have a save/load.cs that saves all the variables, loads them. What I was doing was saving the time in seconds from when the game closes, and dividing it by the 10 seconds, and getting the premium currency, but there is a big problem I have.

When I closed the game, and say the timer was at 5, even if 20 seconds went by, the timer would be start back up at 10. So what I wanted to do was take the remaining time from the timer, and subtract it from the total seconds the game was down, take the modulation of the total seconds (15) and time to tick (10) to get 5 remaining seconds, then start my timer back at 5 when I load the game up, take an int of the total seconds(15) / time to tick (10) to get 1. I then wanted to increase premium currency by 1, for when the 5 seconds went to 0, then 1 because the remaining int of total seconds and time to tick is 1, then set the clock back at 5 seconds, which was leftover.

This sounds very confusing and it made me very confused trying to write this script, but I hope that when I put the code down you guys understand what I am trying to get at. I am adding comments on what I am trying to do in the code, not sure if it is all 100% correct or not.

PremiumCurrencyTimerManager.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class PremiumCurrencyTimerManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameManager GM; //Game Manager, holds most of my variables
    public Text text; //Text that holds the timer, and premium currency and max premium currency I can hold.
    public Button collect; // this button collects the currency
    public int currencyToCollect; //This is the variable that holds my currency
    public int maxCurrencyToCollect; //Max of currency I can hold before I collect
    public int timeToTick = 10; //Time to tick +1 currency
    public TimeSpan showTimeLeft; //Time left on countdown
    public TimeSpan endTimeLeft; //0 seconds, if the time left = this variable then add a currency

    private void Awake()
    {
        showTimeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeToTick); //When this game first starts the time left = start time
        endTimeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0); //variable that shows how many seconds to add a currency, when timer reaches 0 add a currency


        collect.onClick.AddListener(onCollect); //When the button is clicked call onCollect()        
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(getCurrency(showTimeLeft)); //Start the countdown, in the background.

        StartCoroutine(showTimer()); //Shows the actual countdown.
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        text.text = showTimeLeft + "\n\n" + currencyToCollect.ToString() + "/" + maxCurrencyToCollect.ToString();

        if (showTimeLeft <= endTimeLeft)
            showTimeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeToTick); //If the timer reaches 0, restart at timeToTick, I think my main problem with the save/load is that if I stop the game at 2 seconds, it starts the timer back up at 2 seconds because thats what was saved, and it adds a currency anyway.

    }

    public void onCollect() //Called when button is clicked, moves the currency I need to collect to my variable page so I can use it
    {
        GM.premiumCurrency += currencyToCollect;
        currencyToCollect = 0;
    }

    public void addCurrency() //Call this when the timer reaches 0 to add a currency
    {
        if (currencyToCollect < maxCurrencyToCollect)
            currencyToCollect++;
        else
            currencyToCollect = maxCurrencyToCollect;
    }

    public IEnumerator getCurrency(TimeSpan timeInSecs) //Background timer
    {
        int x = timeInSecs.Seconds;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(x);
            addCurrency();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator showTimer() //Timer we see, subtracts 1 per second
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            showTimeLeft = showTimeLeft.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));            
        }
    }
}
```

SaveLoad.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class SaveLoad : MonoBehaviour{

    public GameManager GM;
    public PremiumCurrencyManager PCM;
    public long ticksSinceClose;
    public long totalSeconds;
    public int mailboxTicks;
    public long test;
    public long test2;
    public long b;


    public void Save()
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat");

        PlayerData data = new PlayerData();

        data.currencyToCollect= PCM.currencyToCollect;
        data.maxCurrencyToCollect= PCM.maxCurrencyToCollect;
        data.premiumCurrency= GM.premiumCurrency;
        data.showTimeLeft = PCM.showTimeLeft;


        bf.Serialize(file, data);
        file.Close();
}

    public void Load()
    {
        if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat", FileMode.Open);
            PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();

            ticksSinceClose = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks - data.gameCloseTicks;
            totalSeconds = ticksSinceClose / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;

            if (totalSeconds > data.showTimeLeft.Seconds)
            {
                totalSeconds -= data.showTimeLeft.Seconds; //Subtract this because it was what was left on the clock, and add a premium currency
                PCM.premiumCurrency++;
            }

            test = totalSeconds % PCM.timeToTick; //temp variable that takes the remainder of the seconds and time to tick, to get the seconds that needs to be put on the clock when we load the game

            PCM.maxCurrencyToCollect= data.maxCurrencyToCollect;
            GM.premiumCurrency = data.premiumCurrency ;

            PCM.showTimeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(test);

            PCM.premiumCurrency = data.premiumCurrency;

            mailboxTicks = (int)(totalSeconds/ PCM.timeToTick); //this is just the int of the remainder, so we can add it as premium currency, we take the modulation before and make it the time left. I dont want fractions of a premium currency 

            if (mailboxTicks + PCM.premiumCurrency < PCM.maxCurrencyToCollect)
                PCM.premiumCurrency += mailboxTicks;
            else
                PCM.premiumCurrency = MaM.maxCurrencyToCollect;


        }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class PlayerData
    {
        public long gameCloseTicks;

        public int currencyToCollect;
        public int maxCurrencyToCollect;
        public int PremiumCurrency;
        public TimeSpan showTimeLeft;
    }
}
```

I hope I make more sense now, there should seem like an easier way to do this! The result I get now when I close the game and load it is it goes straight to the max currency even if I only close and reopen the game for 2 seconds.

Comment: So...`System.Time.now`?